# Jefimenko's equations contradiction between free space solutions

Tags: electromagnetism, boundary-conditions, plane-wave

In [Jefimenko's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko%27s_equations), which are a solution to Maxwells equations. Each term has either $\rho $ or $J$ in it.

Setting $\rho$ and J to be zero, Should reduce to the electromagnetic plane wave equation?

But it does not.

and $r'$ isnt even defined properly for free space I'm guessing as well.

Why is this the case?
and has it got to do with the $+ c$ in the integration?

Comment: Not particularly , however I'm pretty sure I've applied this when solving a few differential equations, Is it e.g  transient solution + particular solution = general solution? but no I'm not that comfortable with jt

Comment: Sorry our edits crossed. It just a property of linear equations. It's the same with linear ODE's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jefimenko's equations are the solutions to Maxwell's equations assuming the fields vanish at infinity and that their initial conditions are compatible with Jefimenko's equations. However, if the solutions are not assumed to vanish at infinity or one takes a different set of initial conditions (for example, by assuming there is a plane wave), then one must add a solution of the homogeneous Maxwell's equations (i.e., Maxwell's equations with charges and currents set to zero) to completely fix the initial and/or boundary conditions chosen. See, e.g., the discussion on Zangwill's [*Modern Electrodynamics*](https://www.cambridge.org/highereducation/books/modern-electrodynamics/E5448C70CBF3651B2056F28EBF859AE9#overview), Chap. 15, p. 509.

Yes, the problem is quite similar to the $+c$ of solving ordinary differential equations. Since Maxwell's equations are a system of PDEs, it gets a little more subtle, but in essence that is what is happening.

As for the $\mathbf{r'}$ notation, this is often used to indicate the variable being integrated over, as opposite to the point $\mathbf{r}$ where one is evaluating the field. $\mathbf{r'}$ is still defined for free space, but the integral will vanish identically.

You might want to take a look at Wald's [*Advanced Classical Electromagnetism*](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691220390/advanced-classical-electromagnetism). The first chapter (there is a preview of it available at the link I provided) has a discussion on how the fields are not completely defined by the charges and currents. It doesn't explicitly mention Jefimenko's equations, but it discusses pretty much the same issues.

Comment: That paper is very insightful. I have never actually thought about the connection between the homogenous and inhomogeneous equations, and have always regarded the plane wave solution as unrealistic. Yet maxwells equations perfectly allow such a solution "overlayed" onto of the inhomogeneous solution. Could it be the case that in fact there is a fundamental plane wave through all of space (as maxwells equations allow) But we as humans just set it to be zero( or our instruments cannot detect) and I agree with the author, coulombs law imprints the idea on people that the fields must vanish at

Comment: infinity, when the full maxwells equations doesn't necessarily imply it to be.

Comment: @jensenpaull Yes, there could be a plane wave or some other more complicated solution as a "background solution", but experimentally we notice that usually it isn't as relevant as the fields generated by charges and currents. These are issues that are often overlooked in other textbooks, but Wald's text indeed makes a wonderful job of making them clear

Comment: Why would it be some other complicated background solution? is it because solutions can be added together to form new ones? How does This relate to general relativity/quantum fluctuations? as if there IS a plane wave then the energy density over all of space would be different, causing gravity to be different. I have also remember reading something about quantum fluctuations being the worst prediction as our theoretical value is different then experiment. could this be due a plane wave background? The expansion of the universe and plane wave solutions seem to be connected,? as they are

Comment: the homogeneous solutions

Comment: Also I don't suppose you COULDNT tell me the DOI for this paper, scihub doesn't seem to want to NOT let me see it

Comment: Another possible background solution would be a spherical wave, for example. The other questions seem to go far from the original question, so I suggest asking a new one to cover them (the comments section is intended to provide further clarification on the answer/question, not for extended discussions). 

As for the DOI, notice this is not a paper, but a book. It hasn't been launched yet and it scheduled to March 2022. For now, the [publisher's preview](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691220390/advanced-classical-electromagnetism#preview) is all there is available

Comment: Also, I don't know how to obtain the retarded potentials, so this is wrong. But, if a background E field  was a spherical wave, it would also vanish at infinity... so why does imposing the boundary condition that E=0 at infinity give a unique solution? as if there wasn't a spherical wave, it would also vanish at infinity.

Comment: @jensenpaull Oh, I made a mistake on my answer, I just corrected it. Maxwell's equations are a [hyperbolic system of PDEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_partial_differential_equation) and hence the well-posed problem is not a boundary value problem, but an initial value problem. One can have a spherical wave on top of the non-homogeneous solution. Jefimenko's equations need to assume an initial condition.

Comment: Ah thank you, Was  confused for a second there :)

Comment: Do you know any other resources discussing the possibility of this background EM Field. I cannot find anything online about this. Even in the Wikipedia for the retarded potentials it discusses nothing about the assumptions on specific initial conditions

Comment: @jensenpaull I've never seen anyone discussing them explicitly on the context of Jefimenko's equations. I suggest searching for uniqueness theorems on solutions for Maxwell's equations. Maybe try the references on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetism_uniqueness_theorem)

Answer (score 1):

Are you famiiar with the  concept of a *particular solution* and a *complementary function* for the solution of linear differential equations?  Jefimenko is a particular solution.  Solutions of the  "plane  wave equation" can be added as you like  to satisly the boundary conditions.

Comment: Do you have any links to resources applying this topic specifically in the context of jefimenkos equations?

Comment: And I'm guessing jefimenkos equations are derived under the condition that the fields vanish at infinity thus eliminating the plane wave term?

Comment: You can add any ${\bf J}=0$ and $ \rho=0$  solution  to  Jefimenko and still satisfy Maxwell.

Comment: Accepting nickolas' answer purely for the statement that jefimenkos equations are the particular solution when the fields vanish and infinity. and his link. Thank you for the answer though!